# Fetching SubString from the String in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a Website where the userID differs for every login, 
Say for example 
When i login with userID 'Username1' this contains 0 to 8 characters, similarly if i login with userID 'Username123' contains 0 to 10 characters

I need to automate in such a way, that for every login system stores the user ID in a variable as follows

```
String FullUsername=driver.findElement(MyTeamInboxPage.username).getText();
```

My result for the userID 'Username1' would be 
Username1

I am gonna take substring from 4 to till end as follows

```
String actual=Fullactual.substring(4, 8);
```

But the sub string code will not work for every userID. How can i change my SubString code end character alone in such a way, it should work for every User ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
String actual=Fullactual.substring(4, Fullactual.length());
```

**Note:** the `endIndex` of substring is exclusive. That means if you want to take a substring upto index 8, endIndex has to be 9. That's why I used `Fullactual.length()`, not `Fullactual.length()-1`

Comment: Thank you so much. It actually worked :-) :-) ......Thanks for the immediate response.